# Facebook SDK Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

We have an app that integrated the facebook login, recently we had received an email from Facebook stating the following:

"1. Your Android or iOS app does not use our native SDKs to initiate Facebook Login. We suggest you implement our native SDKs so that people who are already logged in to their Facebook accounts don't have to log in again. Note that starting October 2, using our native SDKs for login will be required by Facebook Platform Policy I.3. For more information on this, visit:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-sdks/"

But the fact is, our app uses the following for login

```
session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView
```

Which obviously is a function PROVIDED WITHIN Facebook's SDK

And also the app does not require the user to re-log in if he/she is already logged in. We tried to contact FB for clarification but they had not replied since. So can someone tell if our app's facebook login needs to be changed? Or has FB "wrongfully accused" us?